# How can I make Log Files for every Class using Log4j2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I am currently using a Spring Boot Application, where I am logging out every Log into the console.

But Now I wanted to log every log into a specific class file name.

Example

```
class A {
    public void test() {
        log.info("Test method");
    }
}
```

So the log for this code will be in one of the log folder, where the file name will be `A` (the class Name) and log "Test method" will be inside the file `A`.

Comment: While there are surely ways to log in this way I would recommend against it. One point of using logging is to be able to trace how some request was processed, and that involves requires looking up the logs of several method calls in different classes. When you split the log files by class name this because incredibly hard. i.e. the request started in class A, was handed over to some method in class B, which again calls methods in classes C, D and E: how will you bring these logs together?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Actually what i am looking for is when I specify the class which log should be in separate file then all the method invoked in that class then it should be log in that same file.Example Class A in specified then A.log file should be created and if class A has b.method() then that method log also should be present in the A.log file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java code, you do not just have the log statements but also some initializer for the `log` instance, like so:

```
class A {
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(A.class);

    public void test() {
        log.info("blah");
    }
}

class B {
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(B.class);

    public void test() {
        log.info("blah");
    }
}

class C {
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(C.class);

    public void test() {
        log.info("blah");
    }
}
```

Now in your logging configuration (log4j2.xml) the loggers match categories, and you can define which category goes to which appender. Finally you can setup appenders to write to file or console or other destinations, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Appender type="File" name="File" fileName="/path/to/logfiles/AandB.log">
            <Layout type="PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </Layout>
        </Appender>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger level="info"  name="A"><!-- speficially route these messages to the file appender only -->
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/> 
        </Logger>
        <Logger level="info"  name="B"><!-- speficially route these messages to the file and console appenders -->
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/> 
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/> 
        </Logger>
        <Root level="trace"> <!-- per default route all log statements to the console, which is where logging for C will end up -->
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>    
</Configuration>
```

While it is possible, I do not see it very efficient to create a separate logfile (=> file appender) for each single class. But on library level this can make sense.

See details on https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for this approach but the ${filename} is not working can you please help me why?

Comment: I'm sorry - that is a reference to a property. I replaced it with some example filename. You will have to put your filename anyway. Explanation is in the documentation I referenced.